# Programmatic access to Java documentation

Tags: java, api, documentation

Is there an api to programmatically access to the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)? Something similar to what editors/IDEs like Eclipse do for IntelliSense. Surely, the javadoc generated html can be parsed and indexed, but would be great to know if something already exists as a standalone package.

Update:
To be clear, I am trying to get a programmatic access to the documentation for the java language implementation. However, there isn't an easy way out, but you have to get the openjdk from Oracle's site and then do `make docs` and supply some doclet to get the output in non-html form. This is what I was trying to avoid from the beginning. So I'm reading all the Makefiles now trying to figure out why $PLATFORM isn't being resolved and source build is failing!

What I finally settled with:

Scraping html docs. Yep. Realized that'd get my job done.

```
import urllib2
import pymongo

mongo = pymongo.Connection('localhost')
mongo_db = mongo['api_db']
mongo_collection = mongo_db['api_collection']

URL='''http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index-files/index-'''
URL_range = 27+1

def getPageElements(url):
    content=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    elements = soup('dl')
    return elements


def savePageElements(elements):
    for i in elements[0]:
            try:
                    entry={'type_description':str(i.findNext('dt')).split('-')[1].split('<')[0]\
                                    +i.findNext('a').findNext('a').renderContents(),\
                                    'signature':i.findNext('a').findNext('a').renderContents()+i.findNext('b').renderContents(),\
                                    'description': i.findNext('dd').renderContents()\
                            }   
                    print entry
                    insert_id = mongo_collection.save(entry)
            except:
                    pass


def retrieve(str):
     mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({
    'signature': str,
    #'type_description':"Method of java.io.PrintStream"
    })  
    for this_document in mongo_documents:
        print this_document


if __name__=="__main__":
    for i in range(1,URL_range):
            #url=URL+str(i)+".html"
            #print "Processing:", url
            #elements=getPageElements(url)
            #print elements[0]
            #savePageElements(elements)
            retrieve("println(String)")
```

But take a look at [dexy](http://blog.dexy.it/384). If I could have managed to build OpenJDK on Ubuntu without issue - it would have generated nice JSON to play with.

Comment: To build a research prototype for "feature location" and "tracebility" between code and documentation.

Comment: Would it need to version specific?  ie Java 7, Java 6? Or would you need to be able trace between

Comment: Would you need just the core API's or would need the extended API's, ie JavaMail.  Do you want 3rd party API's?

Comment: Not very easy, though Eclipse is doing it. Search for javadoc parser here.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Version specific is not really that much of a concern. But the code bases that I have to experiment with are written in Java 6.

Comment: 3rd parties would also show up in the code bases. I was hoping javadoc might have some intermediate data format that would be independent of the end result type(html/pdf) which can be queried easily. What @Miserable Variable is suggesting I might have to go down that route ultimately - get entire source code of Java and use something like [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org) to generate it in a query-able format. Urgh!

Comment: Yeah, my answer would be a tentative "no". Basically, as far as I'm aware for NetBeans, the process would be to parse the individual JavaDoc's (starting at the index page) and indexing the results, based on package, class, method and possibility field values.  I like the idea though. You could pull the netbeans source code and see if you find the way they do it :P

Comment: Note that javascript can create a HTML version of the sources and create links to it.  Parsing _those_ HTML files may be a very simple solution to what you actually need.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I think OP's starting point is the generated `javadoc` not the sources, e.g. JDK docs.

Comment: I meant _javadoc_, not JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

As you write Eclipse does parse javadoc and does pretty good job of it. It seems it was introduced in [3.2M4](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t54037.html). You may be able to extract the functionality from Eclipse sources, checking with Eclipse community for entry point may be a good place to start.

If that does not work, I guess your starting point would be a plain vanilla HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc tool parses the information out of your Java files and delegates to a *doclet* to translate this structured information into documentation. The standard doclet produces the familiar HTML output but you can [write your own](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/index.html) and tell javadoc to use that instead. This is probably the most robust option if you have the original source code available.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the output of the JavaDoc tool and parse it as XML as [in this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipjdoc/index.html).
- You can also use other documentation extraction tools like [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) and parse their (better) XML output.
- When you have basic parser knowledge, You can write a JavaDoc-extractor by your own. There are a lot of free Java parsers that are a good starting point. (I think this will be the best way for your research prototype).